# remove items from a CSV based off of an array

Tags: powershell

First, this must be done in powershell nothing else is available to me.
Okay, I have a CSV file that looks like this

```
name,  location,   state,  city,       zip,    identity
bob,   uptown      ny,     newyork,    37903,  1001
Will,  downtown,   ny,     brooklyn,   99999,  1010
frank, midtown,    pa,     pitsburg,   46546,  2015
mark,  somewhere,  tx,     dallas,     45644,  1000
Lisa,  here,       nc,     franklin,   46542,  1510
```

I then have an array that looks like this

```
$foo = @ (1000, 2015, 1010)
```

what I want to do is build a new array where the items listed in the foo array are removed.

The expected output in the example given would be

```
name,  location,   state,  city,       zip,    identity
bob,   uptown      ny,     newyork,    37903,  1001
Lisa,  here,       nc,     franklin,   46542,  1510
```

I have tried many things, but so far have been unsucessful in creating this.  BTW, I do not have to have the header info in the new array. the identity field is the only unique field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\aaa.csv
$foo = @(1000, 2015, 1010)
$csvnew = $csv | ? { $foo -notcontains $_.identity }
```

Comment: what does the `?` do, please ;-)

Comment: is an alias of `where-object` cmdlet.

Comment: I tried that particular script and it did not work; however, I used the last part. $csvnew = $csv | ? { $foo -notcontains $_.identity }
and substituted the $foo for one of the actual values, and it removed that value from the $csvnew, which is as intended.
I can now make it work, by putting it into a do while loop.  is that the intent of this particular snippet?

Comment: @Radagast I've tested it with copy and paste your example in question. I've add a missing comma after 'uptown' e remove the space after @. It works. $csvnew contains only row with identity value 1001 and 1510. no needs of any kind of loop here. check again you code ;)

Comment: Thank you Christian, I checked over my code and found that there was an error in CSV file.  thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell 3.0 you can use the new NotIn operator:

```
Import-Csv file.csv | where Identity -notin $foo
```